# Recording the Python script execution method

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I have composed an ArcPy script which is run via a windows scheduler.The same script is loaded into a script tool so a user can run the process manually. I've used: get parameters as text, with or's and not's, to hard-wire the standard variables if they are not speicifed.

```
ReportFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if ReportFolder == '#' or not ReportFolder:
 ReportFolder = "C:\\Data\\GIS"
```

The process runs and during so writes to a text file log, for example:

```
txtFile.write("=    For ArcGIS 10.3.1: Date: "+str(timed)),txtFile.write ('\n')
```

I'd like to record what method was used to execute the script; was it via the windows scheduler, or by the script tool via ArcGIS, or by a python client like PyScripter.

Is anyone aware of some form of os environment thingy that can be called by Python?

Comment: Pass the method of invocation as an argument.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179179/recording-the-arcpy-script-execution-method